# I want to make a temporary answerphone which records MP3s

Tags: python, voip

An artistic project will encourage users to ring a number and leave a voice-mail on an automated service. These voice-mails will be collected and edited into a half-hour radio show.

I want to make a **temporary** system (with as little as possible programming) which will:

- Allow me to establish a public telephone number (preferably in the UK)
- Allow members of the public to call in and receive a short pre-recorded message
- Leave a message of their own after the beep.
- At the end of the project I'd like to be able to download and convert the recorded audio into a format that I can edit with a free audio-editor.

I do not mind paying to use a service if it means I can get away with doing less programming work. Also it's got to be reliable because once recorded it will be impossible to re-record the audio clips. Once set up the whole thing will run for at most 2 weeks.

I'm a python programmer with some basic familiarity with VOIP, however I'd prefer not to set up a big complex system like Asterisk since I do not ever intend to use the system again once the project is over. Whatever I do has to be really simple and disposable. Also I have access to Linux and FreeBSD systems (no Windows, sorry).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I use twilio, very easy, very fun.

Comment: Wow... it really does look like fun!

Comment: Dammit, unfortunately USA only - it needs to be a UK number otherwise nobody will call.

Comment: This is no longer true: http://www.twilio.com/international-calling-rates

Looks like UK is equal cost to US: $0.03/min.

Answer (score 2):

Skype has a [voicemail](http://skype.com/allfeatures/voicemail/) feature which sounds perfect for this and I suppose you would need a [SkypeIn number](http://skype.com/allfeatures/onlinenumber/) as well

Comment: Is there a way to get the Skype answerphone messages as audio-files? That would be perfect as it would require almost no programming at all!

Comment: Yes. Although it seems you have to use third-party tools: 
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=111576

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/). I don't think it will become any easier than using an existing system.

Maybe you can find someone in the asterisk community to help set up such a system.

Comment: I already have some experience of using Asterisk - it's a great system but I want something that requires a lot less configuration. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Sipgate.co.uk, they provide a free UK dial in number and free incoming calls.  Not so relavant for you but they also have a python api.

They are a SIP provider and there are many libraries (e.g. http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial ) for sip in python - so you could set up a python application to login to your sipgate account, pick up and incoming calls and dump the sound to a wav/mp3 whatever.